# The filename of a just loaded file via FileReference is not available

Tags: apache-flex

To load 3 files locally into the Flash Player, one might using something like this manage the sequence after the user has chosen the files...

```
    private function uploadList(evt:Event):void{

        var arr:Array = fileReferenceList.fileList;

        for each(var item:FileReference in arr){
            item.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onFileLoadComplete);
            item.load();
        }

    }
```

// Step 2 - go ahead and load the file and wait for step 3...this will be called three times in this use-case.

```
    private function onFileLoadComplete(e:Event):void {

        var loader:Loader = new Loader();

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoadComplete);
        loader.loadBytes(FileReference(e.target).data);
    }
```

// Step 3 - Flash Player has loaded the file and is ready for processing...
// this example is an image being stuffed into a BitmapData object...

```
private function onDataLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(e.target.content).bitmapData;
        var loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
```

...

}

// Step 4 - Where is the filename and file byte size located for each file passing through Step 3?

I've not been able to locate this data in existing objects.

My own resolution....

I stuff the info into a simple dictionary and retrieve it later.

Perhaps there are other solutions out there?

```
private function onFileLoadComplete(e:Event):void {

        if(FileReference(e.target).data.length == 0){
            return;
        }           

        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        filenameDict[loader] = String(FileReference(e.target).name);

        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoadComplete);
        loader.loadBytes(FileReference(e.target).data);
    }


    private function onDataLoadComplete(e:Event):void {
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(e.target.content).bitmapData;

        var loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
        var file:String = filenameDict[loader];
        delete filenameDict[loader];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with arrays but as you can see from the code, `Dictionary` is the easier way.

```
var files:Array = [];
var loaders:Array = [];
private function onFileLoadComplete(e:Event):void 
{
  var loader:Loader = new Loader();
  files.push(e.target);
  loaders.push(loader);
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataLoadComplete);
  loader.loadBytes(FileReference(e.target).data);
}
private function onDataLoadComplete(e:Event):void
{
  var bitmapData:BitmapData = Bitmap(e.target.content).bitmapData;
  var loader:Loader = Loader(e.target.loader);
  var index:Number = loaders.indexOf(loader);
  var file:String = FileReference(files[index]).name;
  /*
   * Clear the arrays to get rid of unwanted references that might 
   * prevent them from being garbage collected.
   * */
  files.splice(index);
  loaders.splice(index);
}
```

---

*I was oblivious to FP10's FileReference when I made the first version of this post.*